# Adding organization metadata to RSS/Atom feed?

Tags: metadata

What is the most correct / typical / popular namespace to associate an organization name, logo, and maybe website metadata with an RSS 2 (or Atom) feed entry? Can we just use https://schema.org/Organization for that? Organization can be understood as a creator of the entry or original creator (in reposting case) or maybe some more involved relation approximated with the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best representation I've seen are mixtures of Microformats, Schema.org, and Dublin Core. Essentially, utilize the semantics that are best for your situation; it sounds `rel="author"` is what you are looking for in differentiating blog posts. [Indie Web Camp's feed](https://indieweb.org/wiki/api.php?hidebots=1&days=7&limit=50&action=feedrecentchanges&feedformat=atom) and [A List Apart's feed](https://alistapart.com/main/feed/) are great examples of metadata in feeds.
Running them [through pin13's validator](http://pin13.net/) exposes their semantics; not surprisingly, nothing renders in Google's "Structured" Data Testing Tool.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit how microformats come into picture here? Do you mean `<description>` HTML contents of the RSS can contain those? `<author>` seems to be only for email in the specification.

Comment: on ALA's feed, the anchor elements that are children of the author element, have `rel="author"` as an attribute/value. more on [`rel="author"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-author)

Comment: yes, what I mean is `<author>` is for email of the author according to RSS2 spec: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Falistapart.com%2Fmain%2Ffeed%2F . Indie Web Camp's feed is at least valid.

Comment: i'm not 100% on ala's use of `<author>` here, but i trust that they know what they are doing; they've been around for awhile, pushing the envelope of web standards. validation is a great tool, but its still just a tool. for awhile there, html would fail validation using fb/twitter `<meta>` elements...they didn't break anything in terms of rendering/user agents, but since they weren't in the spec, they failed.